# Question on hold

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions, on-hold

My question has been put on [on hold] because:

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Richard Scriven, agstudy, Pascal, Ende Neu, Deena 6 hours ago
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
>       If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question.

I edited and wrote my question in a much clearer form, however it is still on hold. Is there a way to know if I still need to work on that question?

> #### Question: [Using apply function to average dataframe groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466607)

Comment: If you want meta to review it, post a link to the question. Otherwise, the edit put it in the reopen queue, and there is nothing more to do.

Comment: [It's this one, isn't it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466607/apply-function-to-average-dataframe-groups)

Comment: I defer to those that know R, but at first I didn't see an actual question; it was more of a, "This is what I want to do" sort of deal.  I don't know what you're having trouble with though, nor do I know what you attempted to get to that state, so I agree with (but won't vote on) it being off-topic.

Comment: The process for reopening closed questions is described at http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your post seem to be asking two questions.

The first one is:

> I would like to know whether I can use an apply approach instead of aggregate. Is this going to speed up the process?

You have shown the code you use and now you ask if doing something else is *going to speed up the process*. I'm not familiar with R but you and the community can only know by trying it out and see if this different approach speeds up a process.

Instead you could have done that yourself, and then ask why your assumption about one way of solving has different characteristics than the other.

Always be explicit about non-concrete indicators like *speed up*. Ask instead:

> This solution runs in 1 minute 10 seconds for 1000 items. That needs to be less than 20 seconds. I tried the apply approach but that reduced it by 10 seconds.

The second one is about subtracting stuff. Besides that I feel the question would be better asked separately as it's also missing any attempt from you so people visiting your question deemed it unclear where you were stuck. At least one visitor down voted your question, maybe for that reason.

If you fix your question based on the suggestions presented here I'll consider using one of my re-open votes. Do note that [3 reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9451425) didn't feel the question was improved enough when they say it to cast a re-open vote. If I use my re-open vote your question still needs one other member to follow my vote.

Comment: I agree that the question could be be dived in two and in future I'll post just one question/post. In regard to the first part of the question, it is actually pretty clear that I am asking for an alternative `"apply"` approach. This, according to my beginner theoretical knowledge, should make processes faster. Please notice that I have posted a simplified example; this in order to make the exchange of information faster-my real work is bigger for this reason speed matters.

Comment: @Al14 Why in the future? Why not now? You can edit your question down to one question just using the 'edit' link on your question.

Comment: I removed the second part of the question